# "Missing Authentication Token" Error while saving lambda in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am getting "Missing Authentication Token" error when I am trying to save a lambda in Node.js:

[image]

I am following this tutorial and followed all the steps as it is [AWS creating a custom bot, adding the lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html)

Is there anything that I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: Does this problem persist when you log out of the AWS console and then log back in again?

Comment: I have this exact same error sometimes when I forget to create the lambda in the serverles file

Comment: Yes, @thomasmichaelwallace. I logged out and tried again. I also used Internet Explorer (which I never used to login to AWS console), but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: Got the problem. This could be because I was saving it while being behind corporate proxy. I tried the same at my home network and it worked like a charm. So, proxies are always a pain to troubleshoot.